# General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm stuck with this error. I explain the view a little.

I have a form to create a New project, when I created it I hide the form and I save it, then I render an other form to create translation, I create it and I save it, and finally I render an other form to create client, I create and it save it.

At this moment, just in the same function, I want to save another value in another table.

I want to save in client_projects the value of the last client_id and project_id saved in database.

So i try this:

```
$client_project = new Client_Project();
            $client_project->client_id = DB::table('clients')->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(id) from clients)"))->get();
            $client_project->project_id = DB::table('projects')->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(id) from projects)"))->get();
            $client_project->save();
```

But it give me the error of the title::

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":49,"name":"hola","slug":"hola","priority":1,"created_at":"2017-08-03 13:53:35","updated_at":"2017-08-03 13:53:35"}]' for column 'client_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `client_project` (`client_id`, `project_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ([{"id":49,"name":"hola","slug":"hola","priority":1,"created_at":"2017-08-03 13:53:35","updated_at":"2017-08-03 13:53:35"}], [{"id":40,"slug":"1","order":40,"public":1,"pathheader":"\/tmp\/phpf8NUkb","pathhome":"\/tmp\/php9zepk7","created_at":"2017-08-03 13:49:53","updated_at":"2017-08-03 13:49:53"}], 2017-08-03 13:53:35, 2017-08-03 13:53:35))
```

The full function where i create the client and i try to create the client_projects is this

```
public function storeProjectsClients(Request $request) {
            $client = new Client();
            $client->name = $request->input("nameClient");
            $client->slug = $request->input("slugClient");
            $client->priority = $request->input("priorityClient");
            $client->save();
            $client_project = new Client_Project();
            $client_project->client_id = DB::table('clients')->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(id) from clients)"))->get();
            $client_project->project_id = DB::table('projects')->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(id) from projects)"))->get();
            $client_project->save();
        }
```

I know it's better to pass using json the value of the project_id and client_id, cause if some users are doing this at the same time it will give problems, but anyway, this is only for me.

Any help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Just look at the insert query. You are trying to write "
[{"id":49,"name":"hola","slug":"hola","priority":1,"created_at":"2017-08-03 13:53:35","updated_at":"2017-08-03 13:53:35"}]" to a column that expects an integer.

Comment: I check it a lot of times.. id is integer, name is string, slug is string, priority is integer. Where you find the error?

Comment: You are writing the whole string "[{"id":49,"name":"hola","slug":"hola...." to the database column that expects an integer.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `get()` method, you are selecting rows corresponding to you query in the table, but the foreign key should be the `id` only.

So you need to take only one row (using `first()` considering you should have only one row) and select only the id.

You can try the following code :

```
$client_project = new Client_Project();
$client_project->client_id = DB::table('clients')->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(id) from clients)"))->first()->id;
$client_project->project_id = DB::table('projects')->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(id) from projects)"))->first()->id;
$client_project->save();
```

Comment: This give me this error: `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.
` know why?

Comment: Did you do it with `get()` ?. If yes can you try with `first()`, I forgot to change it

Comment: With first works. Made my day, if i can give you +100 i will do haha. Thanks mate;)